# Declaring static initializer block before declaring variable explanation

Tags: java, static-block, variable-initialization

How does this code work fine and prints 9?

```
public class Dog{

    static {
        age=9;
    }

    static int age=7;

}
```

And this code doesn't compile(illegal forward reference)? Notice I changed age in static block.

```
public class Dog{

    static {
        age++;
    }

    static int age=7;

}
```

Another question is how do both of them even work? From my prior Java knowledge I knew a rule that:

> you can't access variable before declaring them

. So how does static block know what variable **age** actually is?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Dog{

   static {
      age=9;
   }

   static int age=7;
}
```

Static blocks and static variable initialisations are executed in the order in which they appear in source file. ([java documentation point 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

In Above case, you are doing an assignment before declaring a variable which is permitted by java in certain cases. [Forward References During Field Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)

> The use is on the left-hand side of an assignment;

```
public class Dog {
   static {
      age++;
   }
   static int age=7;
}
```

In this case, you are reading it before declaring it which is not permitted. That's why you are getting an illegal forward reference exception.

> j = 200;
>     // ok - assignment 
>     j = j + 1;
>     // error - right hand side reads before declaration